# R-squared from rolling regression in Stata 12

Tags: regression, stata, r-squared

I am aiming to do a rolling regression in Stata, and I simply want to obtain the R-squared. I am aiming to keep it simple, I am not writing a whole program but if this is necessary, I am open for such suggestions as well.

At the moment I have lines with which I only obtain the estimates of the beta coefficients and the standard errors. I just enter this straight into the GUI.

tsset time

rolling _b _se, window(60) keep(date) clear: regress y x

The stepsize is 1 and the corresponding command is therefore omitted from the codelines. I based this on the stata manual (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsrolling.pdf). However, in this manual I do not see the R-squared mentioned. I also googled the subject extensively and looked into statalist but am unable to find a solution.

Suggestions to obtain a column that includes the R-squared of each regression would be much appreciated.

Daan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stata. It should probably be asked on a list devoted to Stata. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'd do something like:

```
rolling r2=e(r2), window(60) keep(date) clear: regress y x
```

as I read the help pages. That will save the R-squared values into `r2`. You could also use `e(r2_a)` for the adjusted R-squared.

Comment: That works indeed, appreciate it.